# Global variable doesn't update until function finishes?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to prevent a function (^F1) from being run twice at the same time.

To do this, I'm trying to use a global lock variable; the function needs to release the lock to enable another function call.

Now, this below code would work in Java, but it's not working in AHK. The problem is that, in AHK, the global "is_locked" does not update until ^F1 has finished. This defeats the purpose of using a global lock variable to prevent simultaneous function calls.

How can I fix this?

```
is_locked := False

set_lock()
{
    global is_locked
    is_locked := True
}

remove_lock()
{
    global is_locked
    is_locked := False  
}

^F1::
    global is_locked
    if(is_locked)
    {
        ; doesn't print until after 10 seconds, even if I am spamming ^F1
        MsgBox, "locked"
        return
    }
    set_lock()
    Sleep 10000
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take note that `is_locked` is a [super-global variable](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#SuperGlobal).

```
global is_locked := false

set_lock()
{
    is_locked := true
}

remove_lock()
{
    is_locked := false  
}

^F1::
    if (is_locked)
        return

    set_lock()
    MsgBox, "locked"
    Sleep 10000
    remove_lock()
return
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it's robust to use by multiple hotkeys. The toggle method of the other answer isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
global is_locked

toggle_lock() {

    is_locked := !is_locked
    OutputDebug, % is_locked

}

^F1::

    toggle_lock()

    if  is_locked
        ToolTip, locked
    Else
        ToolTip, NOT locked

return
```

Comment: That only works because you're not putting Sleep 10000 at the end of ^F1.

Comment: For me it's working, even with the `Sleep 10000` at the end of the ^F1, but, you must remember, that the ^F1 will only work again, after the sleep time as expired.